# Type 'RefObject<R>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: typeof Room_T | null) => void) | RefObject<typeof Room_T> | null | undefined'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

When I export the Room component with connect, in the App component, the ref of the Room component setting does not work normally. If the connect is removed, it works normally. The following is a part of the main code demonstration.``

App.tsx

```
.....
class App extends React.Component<I_PROPS, I_STATE>{
  private refRoom: React.RefObject<Room_T>;
  constructor(props:any){
     super(props);
     this.refRoom = createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={STORE}>
          <Room ref={this.refRoom} />
       </Provider>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

``

```
<Room ref={this.refRoom} />
```

**Error: Type 'RefObject<Room_T>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: typeof Room_T | null) => void) | RefObject | null | undefined'.
Type 'RefObject<Room_T>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject'.
Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
Type 'Room_T | null' is not assignable to type 'typeof Room_T | null'.
Property 'prototype' is missing in type 'Room_T' but required in type 'typeof Room_T'**

Room.tsx

```
....
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
....
export class Room_T extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            ....
        )
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, {
    forwardRef: true
})(Room_T)
```

```
dependencies
    react        = "16.13.1"
    react-redux  = "7.2.1"
    redux        = "4.0.5"
devDependencies
    @types/react       = "16.9.26"
    @types/react-redux = "7.1.8"
    typescript         = "3.9.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with how classes can also be used as types, but `consts` can't. When you export just the base class (without the `connect` statement), your `refRoom: React.RefObject<Room_T>;` is valid, as `Room_T` refers to a class.

However, when you export a connected component, this is no longer a class, and hence cannot be used as a type. Instead you want to use the `typeof` operator to get the actual type like `React.RefObject<typeof Room_T>;`

Hopefully this snippet explains this a bit better:

```js
type I_PROPS = object
type I_STATE = object

class UnconnectedRoom extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return null
  }
  someMethod() {
    console.log('called method')
  }
}

const ConnectedRoom = connect(
  () => {},
  null,
  (stateProps, dispatchProps) => ({}),
  {
    forwardRef: true,
  }
)(UnconnectedRoom)
class App extends React.Component<I_PROPS, I_STATE> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props)
    this.connectedRoomRef = createRef()
    this.unconnectedRoomRef = createRef()
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.unconnectedRoomRef.current?.someMethod())
    console.log(this.connectedRoomRef.current?.someMethod())
    return (
      <Provider store={{}}>
        <ConnectedRoom ref={this.connectedRoomRef} />
        <UnconnectedRoom ref={this.unconnectedRoomRef} />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
  private connectedRoomRef: React.RefObject<typeof ConnectedRoom> // This is not a class and hence we're using the `typeof` operator
  private unconnectedRoomRef: React.RefObject<UnconnectedRoom> // This is a class and can also be used as a type
}
```

Comment: The ts checker cannot check him friendly, although console.log(this.connectedRoomRef.current) is not empty, the IDE cannot recognize all the methods and properties of the containing class

Comment: refs aren't guaranteed to be set during the first render, and this is something that your code needs to handle (using something like `if (ref.current) { // do something }`).

Comment: Yes, I just updated the code and it works fine. The ts checker tells that current is a typeof GrowRoom_T, and the methods and properties of the object class instance cannot be obtained.

Comment: Get current, I want to convert "typeof Room_T" to "Room_T", otherwise I can't know all the method declarations of Room_T class

Comment: Make sure you're not marking the methods as `private`, and you should be able to call the methods regardless of whether it's the `connect`ed or unconnected version. I'm updating the code in my answer to show an example

Comment: I encountered the same error using this code. Even though it works normally, the ts checker will still report an error. These are two image warnings:
https://i.ibb.co/Xz2HSk0/test-1.png
https://i.ibb.co/0FSQQQH/test-2.png

Comment: What is your typescript version? If you're not already on the latest version, are you able to try this with `^3.9.2`? Also what is the version of your `react-redux`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219152/discussion-between-george-jose-and-projin).

Comment: I just added some dependency information, my current version of ts is 3.9.2